# Does RF honour Non breaking space when defining multiline string variables?

Tags: robotframework

In following sort of scenario;

```
${q}   Set Variable
...   first
...      middle  --  still middle
...   second
```

This evaluates to ['first','middle','--', 'still middle', 'second']

Cuz there's 2 spaces before and after --..

Now if I'd replace multiple spaces in the second row with non-breaking space, would RF honour the nbsp's and variable would be:

[first','middle  --  still middle','second']

EDIT;

Answer is No, RF will also break the line even if the separator is nbsp.

Would there be any way around this ?

Comment: Creating strings with two or more spaces is a problem with RF because they are used as parameter separators. You have two workarounds: `middle${SPACE*2}--${SPACE*2}still middle` or `middle\ \ --\ \ still middle`

Comment: @Pekka -- I *know* .. thats why the question explicitly asking about *non breaking space*  that  - according to its name - could be considered to not have the same behaviour ;)

Comment: And yeah, escaping would work to a degree but the data in the variable is SQL and Regular expressions so, using variables or escaping becomes tedious. I do have work around already in place so im good but -- maybe someone should ask Pekka if he would be willing to consider to not consider 2 or more NBSP's as argument separator ? ;)